# best way of migrating  customised metadata associated with source component  into Tridion environment

Tags: migration, metadata, tridion

If we are migrating content from source Content Management System to Tridion, what is the best way of migrating customized metadata associated with the components(content) of source Content Management System into Tridion? Should we directly migrate it to the sql server or is there an option to migrate it in the form of some xml file, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options when migrating content into Tridion.

I can't understand from the above if you are talking about migrating to SQL server as an intermediate format, or directly into the Tridion database. Importing directly into the Tridion database is definitely not a supported solution, and could lead to unpredictable results.

You need to use the API, either the Core Service or the TOM.NET API (If you have Tridion 2011) or the old TOM API if not.

A popular approach is to export all content into an XML format that you can then process with a .NET application.

There's some good articles on migrating content into Tridion by Ryan Durkin [here](http://blog.building-blocks.com/creating-custom-pages-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011), and Nuno Linhares [here](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/importing-content-into-tridion.html).

Answer (score 6):

Migrating directly into SQL Server is unsupported, and the entire system would be unsupported at that point, due to possible data consistency issues.

The most straightforward way is to read the data from the source system, and use the Tridion API to recreate the item.

If migrating metadata, some of the data would likely fit best into a taxonomy, which would mean you'd want to migrate the keywords / structure first, then tag the content as it came into Tridion.

Answer (score 1):

As mention before, migrating directly into the Database is not an option if you are planning to use SDL Tridion as the final CMS.
Apart of the supported mechanism chosen for Migrate, play attention about how you are going to structure the metadata in the new CMS, as depending on the volume, structure, hierarchy, relation across metadata items the process can become complex.
Also play special attention at the Blueprint concept, as probably you can merge duplicated values from the old system into only one that is inherited.

Don't think only in how to put the metadata in the system, also how that Metadata will be used and maintained in the new CMS, in this case SDL Tridion

You can check also a recent post about Migration and plan Migration in general, in case adds some more information

[Can we automate migrating to SDL Tridion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645999/can-we-automate-migrating-to-sdl-tridion/9934000#9934000)